# position: relative, overflow: hidden parent and absolute child

Tags: html, css, position, overflow, drop-down-menu

Okay, here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jGLvk/405/

If you hover the 9012 menu, you will have sliced dropped down submenu that is absolute.
Remove position:absolute, or overflow:hidden from any of its parents: you will have normal working dropdown menu.

“Overflow-y:visible” will just generate a scrollbar instead of showing menu.

Please help me! I need a regular superfish dropdown menu in such tricky ancestors.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the overflow hidden for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, take a look. I'm not sure what the `overflow:hidden` is for, but would it work applied to the div `ul`and not the `div`? If so, well do it, and set the `position: relative` on the div. Take a look -> http://jsfiddle.net/jGLvk/407/

Since the absolutely positioned elements becomes relative to the `div`, it ignores the `overflow:hidden;` set on the `ul`.